# Usage example of the HttpClient.SendRequestAsync method passing a HttpRequestMessage object as an argument

Tags: c#, http, windows-runtime

I'm trying to understand how this [HttpRequestMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httprequestmessage.aspx) class works as an argument to a call to [HttpClient.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn298657.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), according to the last one's documentation the HttpRequestMessage can be used to fill some of the headers in the request that will be made by HttpClient.SendRequestAsync, the thing I still don't understand is how do I manage to fill the HttpRequestMessage.Headers property as it's a "get" only property? If I got it right, the request headers are stored within this collection, but how can I modify it if I'm only allowed to get it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the `Headers` property has an `Add(string header)` method.

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out after writing the question. As the Headers property is a collection I don't need to be allowed to set, I can just get the object from the property and use it's methods to manage the items within it.